# Why is the condition in this if statement written as a multiplication instead of the value of the multiplication?

Tags: conditional-statements

I was reviewing some code from a library for Arduino and saw the following if statement in the main loop:

```
draw_state++;
if ( draw_state >= 14*8 )
    draw_state = 0;
```

`draw_state` is a `uint8_t`.
Why is `14*8` written here instead of 112? I initially thought this was done to save space, as 14 and 8 can both be represented by a single byte, but then so can 112.

I can't see why a compiler wouldn't optimize this to 112, since otherwise it would mean a multiplication has to be done every iteration instead of the lookup of a value. This looks to me like there is some form of memory and processing tradeoff.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to why this was done?

---

Note: I had a hard time coming up with a clear title, so suggestions are welcome.

Comment: To make it obvious (to humans) how the value `112` was arrived at. Presumably `14` and `8` are more meaningful in the context of the rest of the code. You are correct that the compiler will output `112`. There is no memory/processing trade-off. It's basically a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably to explicitly show where the number `112` came from. For example, it could be number of bits in 14 bytes (but of course I don't know the context of the code, so I could be wrong). It would then be more obvious to humans where the value came from, than wiriting just `112`.

And as you pointed out, the compiler will probably optimize it, so there will be no multiplication in the machine code.